# How to Access Child Model data from Parent model in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have these models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False, unique=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = True)
    product_price = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(Product_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Feature(models.Model):
    feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(Product_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    feature_has_value = models.CharField(choices=has_value_choice, max_length = 1, null = False)

class Product_feature(models.Model):
    product_feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='product_feature')
    product_feature_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
```

Now, how can I fetch product_features from product model?
I want to query like this

```
SELECT p.*, f.* from product p, product_feature f where f.product_id = p.product_id ORDER BY P.product_type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the `Product_feature`s by the reverse relation that Django automatically makes, and is named after the `related_name` of the forward relation.

You thus can obtain a `QuerySet` of `Product_feature` objects with:

```
myproduct.product_feature.all()
```

That being said, normally the related name of a `ForeignKey` field should be *plural*, since it is a collection. I therefore advise to rename your `related_name='product_feature'` to `related_name='product_features'`.

Furthermore according to [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), a class name is written in `CamelCase`, so `ProductFeature`, not <s>`Product_feature`</s>.

Comment: Not working it's showing error 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: @SahilShiakh: then you `myproduct` is *not* a `Product` *object*, but the product *class*.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say because I am new in Django please check my models and suggest any changes?